# $0$-dimensional and $G^{⋆⋆}$-regular

Tags: general-topology, analysis

1 ) Why $X = \{ 0 \} \cup \{ 1 / n : n \in \mathbb{N} \}$ is $0$-dimensional ?

2 ) Let $X$ be a space and $G$ a topological group,
Why If $X$ is $0$-dimensional in the sense of ind, then $X$ is $G^{**}$-regular ?

---

Note 1 : $X$ is $0$-dimensional if has a base of clopen sets.

Note 2 : $G^{⋆⋆}$-regular provided that, whenever $F$ is a closed subset of $X$, $x \in X \setminus F$ and $g \in G$, there
exists $f \in Cp(X,G)$ such that $f(x) = g$ and $f(F) \subseteq \{e\}$.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1) The sets of the form $\{\frac1n\}$ and $\{x\in X\mid x<\frac1n\}$ form a basis consisting of clopen sets.

2) $X\setminus F$ is an open neighbourhood of $x$, hence there is a smaller clopen neighbourhood $U$. Define $f(a)=g$ for $a\in U$, $f(a)=e$ otherwise.

Comment: why $f$ is continuous?

Comment: @WrezaShafaghi: $U$ is clopen, hence the inverse image of any (open) subset of $G$ is either $\emptyset$ or $U$ or $X\setminus U$ or $X$, thus always open.

Comment: This is a complete solid answer Hagen +1. I agree with you in meta question.